# localCompare returns 1 when 2 strings are completely same

Tags: javascript

I'm working on my React-Native application. I need to send http post request which returns the token as response or "Wrong Code". So, I'm trying to get response and to see if response is equals to "Wrong Code", that means something went wrong, if not, so I'm gonna get my token and keep going on. Whereas, when I'm trying to compare response with "Wrong Code" through `localCompare` I get 1 when the response is "Wrong Code" - exactly same.
I'm going to share some code to make things more clear.

```
var token = this.state.responseToken;
    console.log("TOKEN: ", token);
    console.log("TOKEN toString: ", token.toString());
    console.log("Wrong Code".localeCompare(token.toString()));
        if((token.toString().localeCompare("Wrong Code"))!=0)
        {
            console.log("VALID CODE");
            Actions.home();
        }
        else
        {
            Alert.alert("Invalid Code");
        }
```

Here is the console.log results.

```
TOKEN:  "Wrong Code"
TOKEN toString:  "Wrong Code"
1
VALID CODE
```

How it is possible to return 1 when comparing two exactly same strings?
Anyone here can help me, please?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not simply using `token === "Wrong Code"`?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/dhetbzh8/), it should, and will, return `0` if the strings are the same, so clearly they aren't

Comment: there are characters that don't get printed, like `String.fromCharCode(0xAD)`. Did you check the length of your two strings? And then there are different characters that look the same, but have different charCodes. Try comparing the two strings charCode by charCode. Maybe you find out why localeCompare says they are different.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that replicates problem

Comment: @Thomas you are right. I checked the length of response and "Wrong Code". They were different. Thank you, man!